# Ubuntu takes random screenshots

Tags: google-chrome, screenshot

The screenshots are taken especially when I turn off the screen when chrome is running and when I come back ubuntu takes screenshots and I cant type anything. I use gnome, so I have to open the app launcher and thus can again start using chrome.

Comment: Your problem is not very clear can you rephrase it clearly.

Comment: I am watching videos online using chrome. If i have to leave, i switch off the screen, on my laptop ( asus x555l). When i come back, chrome takes screenshots and on ubuntu gnome, i have to take the mouse pointer to the top left corner, to minimize the windows or open the application launcher. Only after doind this can i use my keyboard on chrome.

Comment: If you need any more information, please ask specific questions. I don't know what more information you would need. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed in Chrome that might be causing an issue? Is it also reproducible in FF or only in Chrome?